# How can I use unusual non-English characters individually?

Tags: unicode, characters

I would like to user very unusual characters and after some research I still have no idea how it is done. I want, for example the write the word Shīʿah, as in Shīʿah Islam in my dissertation (Note that's a ʿ character, not a single apostrophe ' nor an opening single quote `).

Sadly I can't figure out, how to do that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Few fonts, however expensive, include all characters needed for transliterating Arabic. TeX Gyre fonts do; unfortunately, their left half ring looks more like a superscript c. Try LuaTeX or XeTeX with Brill (http://www.brill.com/about/brill-fonts); the price is perfect for grad students!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a Unicode based TeX such as xetex and Unicode fonts, then it just works out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
%xetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}


\begin{document}

Shīʿah

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

If you are using pdftex, you need to set up utf8 encoding, and then choose suitable fonts for the characters The macron is easily available but I made a poor substitute for the half ring here:

```
\documentclass{article}

%pdftex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012B}{\=\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02BF}{`}% poor approximation

\begin{document}

Shīʿah

\end{document}
```

[image]